# Cyclic imports and lack of generics causing headache

Tags: go

Say I have these two files in golang:

```
// main/a/a.go
import "main/b"

type Model struct {
    ID         int    `json:"id"`
    Me         int    `json:"me"`
    You        int    `json:"you"`
}

func zoom(v b.Injection){

}

func Start(){
  // ...
}
```

and then the second file looks like:

```
// main/b/b.go
import "main/a"

type Injection struct {
    ModelA a.Model
}


func GetInjection() Injection {
    return Injection{
        ModelA: a.Start(),
    }
}
```

so as you can see, these are circular imports, each file imports the other.
So I need to use a 3rd file, and have these two files import the 3rd file.

But I am really struggling how to get this functionality and avoid cyclic imports.

My first step, is to move the `Injection` type into a 3rd file:

```
   // main/c/c.go

    type Injection struct {
        ModelA interface{} // formerly a.Model
    }
```

so now this is what it looks like:

```
a imports c
b imports a,c
```

so no more cycles, however the problem is that I don't know how to create an interface for `a.Model` in `c.go`? An empty `interface{}` like I used above doesn't work, for the normal reasons.

How do I solve this cyclic import problem with these 2 original files?

Comment: Is there a good reason putting them into separate packages in the first place? When using a single package, there's no problem.

Comment: @icza yeah separate packages because there are more files involved, I just distilled it down as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to put into separate packages, you can't have `Model` and `zoom()` in the same package, as `zoom()` refers to `Injection` and `Injection` refers to `Model`.

So a possible solution is to put `Model` into package `a`, `zoom()` into package `b`, and `Injection` into package `c`. `c.Injection` can refer to `a.Model`, `b.zoom()` can refer to `c.Injection`. There's no circle in this:

```
   b.zoom() -------->   c.Injection ---------> a.Model
```

I assume there are other references in your real code which are not in the question which may prevent this from working, but you can move "stuff" around between packages, or you can break it down into more.

Also, if things are coupled this "tight", you should really consider putting them into the same package, and then there is no problem to solve.

Another way to solve circular import issue is to introduce interfaces. E.g. if your `zoom()` function would not refer to `Injection`, the package containing `Model` and `zoom()` would not need to refer to `Injection`'s package.

Inspect what `zoom()` needs to do with `Injection`. If that is method calls, that's already good. If not, add methods to `Injection`. Then you may define an interface in `zoom()`'s package containing the methods `zoom()` needs to call, and change its parameter type to this interface. Implementing interfaces in Go is implicit, there is no declaration of intent. So you can remove the reference in the parameter type, still you will be able to pass `Injection` values to `zoom()`.

Also related, check [Dave Cheney's thoughts about organizing code](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/organizing-go-code/1110/7?u=christophberger):

> I believe code should be organised into packages names for what the package provides, not what it contains. This can sometimes be subtle, but usually not.
>
> For example, http, provides http clients and servers.
>
> As a counter example, package utils is a poor name, yes it provides utilities, but you have no idea what from the name, in truth this package is named for what it contains.
>
> If your project is a library, it should contain one package (excluding examples and possibly utility commands), if it contains more packages, that is a sign that the library is trying to do too many things.
>
> Prefer to avoid multiple packages by default, only split code by package if there is a clear separation of concerns. In my experience many frustrations with complex and possibly circular package structures are the result of too many packages in a project.

Comment: yeah I think I have to put everything in the same package, here comes 20+ files in the same folder lol, namespacing be damned, this sucks btw, not your fault, golangs fault

Comment: @AlexanderMills I think disallowance of circular imports was laid down for fast compilation, but if applied correctly, it can result if cleaner / more logical structure. It also helps you to easier understand the dependencies of your packages / modules.